# Trouble adding user in npm

Tags: npm

I am trying to work through publishing a library component in Angular 2, and am stuck at the basic step of publishing to npm.

I have created a user in the webui, which I can login to successfully.

When I try to run `npm publish` I get the error

> you need to authorize this machine using npm adduser

This is where my problem is if I call `npm adduser` to authorize the machine or `npm login` I get the following output:

> npm verb adduser before first PUT { _id:
>   'org.couchdb.user:xyz', npm verb adduser   name: 'xyz', npm
>   verb adduser   password: 'XXXXX', npm verb adduser   email:
>   'xyz@xyz.com', npm verb adduser   type: 'user', npm verb adduser
>   roles: [], npm verb adduser   date: '2017-08-14T13:21:16.441Z' } npm
>   verb request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:xyz
>   npm verb request new user, so can't send auth npm info attempt
>   registry request try #1 at 2:21:16 PM npm verb request id
>   026a1cd79e30f781 npm http request PUT
>   http://registry.npmjs.org/-/user/org.couchdb.user:xyz

So it seems the fact that I am a new user is the problem, but it is not obvious whether I just have to wait, or do something else to get past this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manually set the registry to `https://registry.npmjs.org/` using the following flag:

`npm adduser --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/`

I ran into this issue when my registry had been overridden.

Comment: Good to hear, was a confusing one for me the first time as well.